# web3.eth.call() to find token balance

Tags: solidity, web3js, tokens

data = web3.utils.sha3('balanceOf(address1)').slice(0,10) + randomstring.generate({ length:24, charset:'0'}) + address1.substring(2);

web3.eth.call({to : config.ContractAddress, data : data}).then((result) =>{
                   console.log("bbbbbbbbb", result);}).catch((e) =>{
                     console.log("eeeeeeeeeee" , e);
                   });

Comment: i am using this contract function to find the balance of token but every time it reurn  0x . i dont know what is going wrong . i want to learn more about how to set data field to calculate the token balance

Comment: In your sha3 expression try `'balanceOf(address)'` (i.e. omit the `1`) - this should give you the correct ABI.